# Table Relationship ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Createstudents < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :students do |t|
          t.string :first_name
          t.string :last_name
          t.string :email 
          :gender 
          t.string :number 
          t.string :college 
          t.string :password 
          t.integer :budget
          t.string :picture 

          t.timestamps
      end
    end
```

I am creating a chinese platform where international students can exchange information about housing. I have a student.rb model.

I want the student to be able to select male or female. How do I do this in the table? with boolean?

also I want each student to specify their housing budget, should budget be in "integer type", or "float type" or "decimal type" ?

Comment: for the budget, use `t.float :budget`. For the gender, I think it depends on whether you are going to query by that field (in that case also add an index)

Comment: @macool if first_name last_name are chinese traditional characters, are they still string?